# How to tell Custom Breadcrumbs which vocabulary to use?

Tags: breadcrumbs

In my site I have pages with a single vocabulary called "category" and Custom Breadcrumbs displays the taxonomy hierarchy and it works.
[image]
Another content types has several vocabularies, including "category". But here Custom Breadcrumbs (CB) will not use the category but other vocabulary to generate the trail.

If I exclude the vocabularies I don't want CB to use to only allow "category", then no breadcrumb is displayed.

[image]

The only difference I see between those content types is the order in which I have created fields. Category was the last field I created for my second content type

So how can I force CB to use category as vocabulary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on my site. I managed to fix it the hard way.

Edit custom_breadcrumbs_taxonomy/custom_breadcrumbs_taxonomy.inc

Add these lines after line 20:

```
$query->condition("v.vid", 2); // 2 is the id of vocab You want to use
$query->orderBy('v.weight');
$query->orderBy('t.weight');
$query->orderBy('t.name');
```

So You have:

```
...
$t_alias = $query->join('taxonomy_term_data', 't', 'r.tid = t.tid');
$v_alias = $query->join('taxonomy_vocabulary', 'v', 't.vid = v.vid');
$query->fields( $t_alias );
$query->condition("r.nid", $node->nid);
$query->condition("v.vid", 2);
$query->orderBy('v.weight');
$query->orderBy('t.weight');
$query->orderBy('t.name');
$result = $query->execute();
$terms[$node->vid][$key] = array();
...
```